# Using The > out.txt Command C#

Tags: c#

I am creating a console application. I want to use the > cmd command so when users use my application they can specify they want the output to be written to a text file of their choise via the > out.txt syntax.

I could handle this by parsing the args of the console application for a '>' and then writing the file (sample below). But is there a more elegant way to handle this?

```
   public void Run(string[] args)
        {



            switch (args[0])
            {
                case "/a":
                    {
                         Console.WriteLine("Hi There");
                         Console.WriteLine();
                        return;
                    }
```

When I enter myApplication.exe /a code runs fine
When I enter myApplication.exe /a >out.txt the code doesnt write anything to the console and am not sure the directory where out.txt is (if anywhere)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't something you need to write into your program; it's handled by CMD.EXE.  All you have to do is write to the console via `Console.Write` or `Console.WriteLine`.  Then, if the user of your application wants to redirect standard output using `>`, he or she can.

As a side note, even if you try to catch and interpret the '>', you'll never see it because CMD.EXE will already have parsed the command line and interpreted something like this:

```
myprog.exe > foo.txt
```

as "Run myprog.exe with no arguments and redirect its output to foo.txt"  The argument list passed to your program won't contain the `>` or `foo.txt`.

Comment: Where does it write the file to? it is not working for me

Comment: It writes the file to the path you specify.  If you don't specify a full path (just a filename), it'll get written to the current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

The command line will handle this for you by default. If your application writes to the console using Console.WriteLine(...), or any other method to write to the console, the user can always pipe output to a file using the '>' symbol. That is built into the Windows command prompt itself.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to do any of that - the command line will do it for you. Just do console.write and it will work